# Windows Batch - List files based on a wild card

Tags: loops, batch-file, window

I have a small batch job that needs to delete files in a folder based on some wildcard parameters. The delete functionality works but i also need to log the files that are deleted in a separate log file. 
All my program does is loop the wildcard variables and combine them together before running a del command.
But how can i list all the files that will be delete?

Here is my batch program :

```
set source[0]="C:\WORK\1\"

set source[1]="C:\WORK\2\"

set source[2]="C:\WORK\3\"

set NameStart[0]="e3"

set NameStart[1]="e4"

set NameMid[0]=*

set NameMid[1]=

set NameEnd[0]=".gz"

set NameEnd[1]=*






date /T  >log.txt

time /T  >>log.txt

echo Delete commands to be executed : >> log.txt

echo Delete commands to be executed : 


Pause


::loop folders

echo Delete Started...

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set source[') do ( 

::loop files

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('set NameStart[') do (   

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%m in ('set NameMid[') do ( 

        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%e in ('set NameEnd[') do (     

                del %%s%%b*%%m*%%e   2> nul 

                echo del %%s%%b*%%m*%%e  >> log.txt         



        )
        )
    )
)

echo Delete Finished!

Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
del /s /q "C:\WORK\1\Yourpattern1" "C:\WORK\1\Yourpattern1.gz" "C:\WORK\2\Yourpattern1" "C:\WORK\2\Yourpattern1.gz" "etc" > logfile.txt
```

Any reason your code is so convoluted.

Comment: I was asked to make a batch file with Parameters so that the user can enter where and what to delete, Thats why i have all those for loops.
The problem i find when i use a del and a wildcard is that i get a File Not found error when it cant find a match which i need to avoid